# Mass update attributes with mock data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm looking to dump my production db to staging, the problem is that there is a lot of data I wish to maintain private, like emails, faxes, names for obvious reasons. I was wondering if there is any gem capable of helping me with this task. I know I could make a script and use something like Faker to generate that data but I was hoping it wouldn't get to that. I'm also not interested in setting all this values to null because staging is also used to make demos and so sending emails and things like that is a necessity. 
Thanks in advance for any insight or help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I solved the problem using [data-anonymization](https://github.com/sunitparekh/data-anonymization). A simple gem designed for this, it has a dsl so the script programming was quite easy. I integrated it with Faker to get production-like data.